# Htmlspecialchars does not work with variable passed

Tags: php, encoding, htmlspecialchars

I'm using `htmlspecialchars` to display Greek letters correctly in my html. For that reason I have:

```
$array = array('sampleGreekString' => 'Ενδιαφερόμαστε για το φορτίο σας')
```

When I call the function like this:

```
htmlspecialchars('Ενδιαφερόμαστε για το φορτίο σας')
```

it works fine and all letters are shown correctly. But when I call it this way:

```
htmlspecialchars($array['sampleGreekString']);
```

on the screen are shown only question marks (?).  How can I fix this?

Comment: I found the real problem. I am using included php file. There is the array with Greek words. When I include it in my view and call htmlspecialchars($array['greekWord']) on the screen are displayed question marks. The problem disappears when the array is defined in the view file. So this is the real problem. Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1):

suppose u have array like this:

```
$array = array('sampleGreekString' => 'Ενδιαφερόμαστε για το φορτίο σας');
```

then try the code this way:

```
function filter(&$value) {
  $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
array_walk_recursive($array, "filter");
```

The above code applies htmlspecialchars to all the array elements.

Comment: @Isadora I tried echo $array['sampleGreekString'] in an script and it worked just fine. Do u use <meta  charset="utf-8"> in your view?

Comment: Yes, it is in my head tag